# Append form to current get link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

**Hello.**

I have link : `"index.php/?city=Something"` and form:

```
<form action="xxx" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="" />
</form>
```

Now I want to link 'get values'.

- **First idea** - use **action** as `"index.php/?city=Something"` - doesn't work.
- **Second idea** - use input hidden(with current gets) before input. Sounds ok - result below.

Now my code looks:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
    <?load_GET_parameters()?>
    <input type="text" name="q" value="" />
</form>

function load_GET_parameters(){
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
     if(strlen($value) == 0)
        continue;
     echo("<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$value'/>");
    }
 }
```

This code have problem when in GET was a 'q' key, so after submit I have TWO the same keys 'q'. And link looks like `"?city=Something&q=das&q=dasds"`

**Where:**

- First q is from 'input hidden' (value from first form)
- Second q is value from submitted form.

I know that I can in php function add condition to not show '$_GET['q'], but this is bad solution for me. I want to use this function in all forms on my page.

**Question:**

- How to send only newer key by form?

Comment: Why do you want to "split the values"? What does that even mean, really? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @cale_b Ahh! Sorry, I mean connect/join not split